# Convert Plain Text Urls to Anchor Tags

Tags: html, regex, url, replace

I realize there's a ton of regex-based solutions to scan a body of text, find the urls and convert them to "a" elements with an href.

However, if you have a block of **html** that contains "a" elements already linked, along with some that are just plain text urls, what's the best way to anchor the ones that aren't already?

```
    <p>
Hello world at www.something.com and also <a href="https://somethingelse.com">Something Else</a>
</p>
```

I'm looking to replace only the www.something.com url with `<a href="www.something.com">www.something.com</a>`

I was thinking maybe regex the existing "a" tags into an array and replace them with a placeholder, then run the usual regex url matcher to replace the remaining plain text urls. Then swap the original "a" elements back in?

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Keep in mind that you need a protocol (like `https://` or `//`) in the `href` or it won't link properly, so that's another component to be aware of.

Comment: True, I was actually going to add that as part of the regex replace I just forgot to include it in my example. Good lookin out!